# PhoneGap: Unfortunately phonegapExample has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am using the latest version of PhoneGap. I am using their code, modified only the App Name and when I run it on the emulator I am getting this error: "Unfortunately phonegapExample has stopped".

My LogCat:

```
12-07 00:04:48.573: I/Process(996): Sending signal. PID: 996 SIG: 9
12-07 00:04:51.814: W/Trace(1013): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-07 00:04:51.814: W/Trace(1013): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-07 00:04:51.814: W/Trace(1013): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-07 00:04:52.043: W/Trace(1013): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-07 00:04:52.053: W/Trace(1013): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-07 00:04:52.053: D/AndroidRuntime(1013): Shutting down VM
12-07 00:04:52.053: W/dalvikvm(1013): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.andreiraileanu.tasker/com.andreiraileanu.tasker.Tasker}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.andreiraileanu.tasker.Tasker" on path: /data/app/com.andreiraileanu.tasker-1.apk
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.andreiraileanu.tasker.Tasker" on path: /data/app/com.andreiraileanu.tasker-1.apk
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
12-07 00:04:52.113: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     ... 11 more
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
      package="com.andreiraileanu.tasker" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity android:name="Tasker" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using their code, modified only the App Name

If you only change the name in the manifest:

```
android:name="Tasker"
```

You will see these errors. You need to rename the class that `android:name` points to as well:

```
public class Tasker ... {
//     This: ^^^^^^ must match the manifest
```

(You will need refactor the file to change the file name too.)

Comment: I can't even find a `CordovaExample` class anywhere. do I have to create the file?