# How to create database in PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, database-connection

I am new in android PhoneGap.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("raddyx", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }
    function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    }

    function errorCB(tx, err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
    }

    function successCB() {
        alert("success!");
    }

</script>
```

I am using above sample code. My database name `raddyx`. I am unable to create database. Can you please say me how to create `raddyx` database in PhoneGap?

Edit - When i run it in my mobile it says `Unfortunately, APP_NAME_HERE has stopped.` If i remove my connection code it works fine.

Comment: check the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753539/phonegap-unfortunately-phonegapexample-has-stopped) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862069/unfortunately-api-demo-has-stopped-phonegap-unaltered-helloworld-app-does-no).

Comment: @frank my app successfully running. But when i am connect to database i am getting `Unfortunately, Raddyx has stopped.` error message.

Comment: can you try to put an `alert()` stmt in the `populateDB()` at the start to check whether it executes the function. is `onDeviceReady()` function getting executed? you need to check every function and find out if it is getting called. It is difficult to know where the issues is with the information that you have provided. Which **version** of cordova are you working on?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database with a function like:

```
function queryDB() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova login", 300000);

        db.transaction(inputDb, errorCB);
    }
```

After that, you call the function inputDb which looks like:

```
function inputeDb(db2) {    
                db2.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS login');
                db2.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login (id_Login INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, UserName VARCHAR(150) NULL, UserPassword VARCHAR(100) NULL, UserHash VARCHAR(50) NULL)');
                db2.executeSql('INSERT INTO login (UserName, UserPassword) VALUES ("'+uname1+'", "'+upass1+'")');

                db2.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MDataT');
                db2.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MDataT (id_MData INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, MData INTEGER)');
                db2.executeSql('INSERT INTO MDataT (id_MData, MData) VALUES ("1", "'+MData+'")');

                //alert("Username and Password - Set in DB");
                location.href="serverLogin.html";
            }
```